# How to calculate how many points in function f are greater than the average of functions g and k?

Tags: coding-style

Consider 3 functions f, g and k

Suppose we want to know for 3. functions from

P={(x,  y )|x=-1,-0.9,-0.8,-0.7....,1 and y=-1,-0.9,-0.8,-0.7....1

this is what i have so far

```
    Clear[f, x, y, g, k]
    f[x_, y_] := x^2+2*Sin[Cos[x*y]]-2 
    g[x_, y_] := x*Cos[x+y]+8*y
    k[x_, y_] := (x^3 + y^3)/(x^3 + e^(y/200))
    p1 = Table[f[x, y], {x, -1, 0.9, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}]
```

How can we calculate how many points in function f are greater than the average of functions g and k? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by the average, pointwise `(g[x,y]+k[x,y])/2` or the average over all 400 points?

Comment: What do you mean by average?

Comment: sorry, the average over all 400 points, thanks